# Django `python manage.py runserver` does not support asyncio&aiohttp

Tags: python, django, python-asyncio, coroutine, aiohttp

In my Django app, I need to proxy a request from the user to other servers. And I use `asyncio/aiohttp client`.

```
#user->request
.....

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = asyncio.ensure_future(self.run(t1, t2, t3))
loop.run_until_complete(future)

......
# response
```

When my django server is started with `python manager.py runserver`,the following error occurs when the user requests.

> RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.

But when I start with `Gunicorn`, everything is ok.

Maybe I should use `new_event_loop`?

Why there is no problem with `Gunicorn`?

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
```

But use of aiohttp in synchronous django will not increase its speed unless you are sending a lot of requests in a view. If you do so, it is better to move that task to some worker (e.g. Celery) or use aiohttp for server too instead of Django.